# Comparison of value entered

Tags: php

Trying to implement: if value entered into "year" field is not a number (NAN) javascript function - doesnt work. Is there an error in my syntax?

Thanks.

```
<?php

    echo "<h1>Testing your Trivia</h1>";
    $ages['Casablanca'] = "1943";
    $ages['Around The World in 80 Days'] = "1956";
    $ages['Patton'] = "1970";
    $ages['Annie Hall'] = "1977";
    $ages['Chariots of Fire'] = "1981";
    $ages['Dances With Wolves'] = "1990";
    $ages['Crash'] = "2005";
    $ages['The Departed'] = "2006";

    $rand_keys = array_rand($ages, 1);

?>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function validate ( form )
{
  var valid = "1234567890";
  if (form.year.value == "" || isNaN(valid) ) {
    alert( "Please enter a year." );
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>

<form method='post' name="inputyear" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
Give the year below won academy award<br>
<Strong>Movie:</strong> <input type='text' name='movie' value='<?= $rand_keys ?>'     readonly='readonly' /><br>
<Strong>Year it Won the Oscar:</Strong> <input type='text' name='year' size="30" /><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>

<?php

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($ages as $movie => $year){
        print_r("Year: $year, Title: $movie <br />");
    }
    echo '</pre>';

    if($_POST['submit']) {
        $movie = $_POST['movie'];
        $year = $_POST['year'];
        $realyear = $ages[$movie];

        echo "<h2>Answer for: $movie</h2>";
        if(array_key_exists($movie, $ages)) {
            echo "Your answer: $year<br/>";
        }
        echo "Correct Answer: $realyear<br/>";
        if ($realyear == $year) {
            echo "<strong style='color:green;'>WELL DONE</strong><br/>";
        } else {
        // wrong
            echo "<strong style='color:red;'>Incorrect.</strong><br/>";
        }
    }    

?>
```

Comment: You want to show user some film name and then let him guess what year yhe film was awarded, did I understood it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code above you would end up with output that includes all of your movies and years each time the page loads.  Since this is supposed to be a quiz, I would imagine that would not be the desired outcome.  I would suggest trying something like:

```
<?php
    echo "<h1>Testing your Trivia</h1>";
    $ages['Casablanca'] = "1943";
    $ages['Around The World in 80 Days'] = "1956";
    $ages['Patton'] = "1970";
    $ages['Annie Hall'] = "1977";
    $ages['Chariots of Fire'] = "1981";
    $ages['Dances With Wolves'] = "1990";
    $ages['Crash'] = "2005";
    $ages['The Departed'] = "2006";

    if(isset($_GET['year'])){
        if($ages[$_GET['movieName']]==$_GET['year']){
            echo "Correct! {$_GET['movieName']} was made in {$_GET['year']}";
        }else{
            echo "Sorry!  Your  answer of {$_GET['year']} is wrong.<br/>";
            echo $_GET['movieName'] . " was made in {$ages[$_GET['movieName']]}";
            }
    }

    $rand_keys = array_rand($ages, 1);

    echo "Give the year below won academy award<br>";
    echo "<Strong>Movie: </strong>$rand_keys <input type='hidden' name='movieName' value='$rand_keys'/><br>";
    echo "<Strong>Year it Won the Oscar: </Strong> <form method='get'><input type='text' name='year' /></form><input type='submit' /> ";
```

In this way, the results are getting checked, if they exist, when the page loads, can provide output, and then ask the question again.

In your code above you're trying to 'get' the value 'key', which doesn't actually exist (in this segment of code). With both $_GET and $_POST, you can refer to form fields from the previous load and refer to those fields by their name.

Finally, because the movie name was read only, I made a change to show how you can handle submitting the name using a hidden form element instead of creating a textbox that would confuse the user.

Comment: Excellent, thank you DMC. If you could briefly explain ' if($ages[$_GET['movieName']]==$_GET['year']) '

Comment: Sure.  $_GET['movieName'] calls the moviename from the form.  When I put it in the $ages[], then I am essentially passing the value of movieName into ages to retrieve the correct element in your array.  Then test the value of your array against the year the person inputed.

Comment: Dmc - this is giving me an error of : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end  on line 26

Comment: I was missing a curly brace after the 'else' block.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the wording of your question, but based on your code I can spot a couple misconceptions.

`$_GET` is an array. If `$_GET` was defined:

```
$_GET = array('movie_title' => 'Patton', 'year' => '1970');
```

Then `$_GET['movie_title']` refers to `'Patton'` and `$_GET['year']` refers to `'1970'`.

The keys of $_GET are given by the names of the input fields, so you will need to give a name to the movie title input.

Then, to ask if the user chose a movie that you know the Oscar winning year for, you would test:

```
if (array_key_exists($_GET['movie_title'], $ages)) {
    ...
}
```

Then to see if they got the answer right, you would test:

```
if ($ages[$_GET['movie_title']] == $_GET['year']) {
    ...
}
```

Hopefully this bears some sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    echo "<h1>Testing your Trivia</h1>";
    $ages['Casablanca'] = "1943";
    $ages['Around The World in 80 Days'] = "1956";
    $ages['Patton'] = "1970";
    $ages['Annie Hall'] = "1977";
    $ages['Chariots of Fire'] = "1981";
    $ages['Dances With Wolves'] = "1990";
    $ages['Crash'] = "2005";
    $ages['The Departed'] = "2006";

    $rand_keys = array_rand($ages, 1);

?>

<form method='post'>
Give the year below won academy award<br>
<Strong>Movie:</strong> <input type='text' name='movie' value='<?= $rand_keys ?>'     readonly='readonly' /><br>
<Strong>Year it Won the Oscar:</Strong> <input type='text' name='year' /><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>

<?

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($ages as $movie => $year){
        print_r("Year: $year, Title: $movie <br />");
    }
    echo '</pre>';

    if($_POST['submit']) {
        $movie = $_POST['movie'];
        $year = $_POST['year'];
        $realyear = $ages[$movie];

        echo "<h2>Answer for: $movie</h2>";
        if(array_key_exists($movie, $ages)) {
            echo "Your answer: $year<br/>";
        }
        echo "Correct Answer: $realyear<br/>";
        if ($realyear == $year) {
            echo "<strong>WELL DONE</strong><br/>";
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect.<br/>";
        }
    }    

?>
```

Comment: Gutterball - thanks :) . This php stuff is so interesting! Woot

Comment: do you see an error in the updated code for "not a number" and empty input: 'code' <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function validate ( form )
{
  var valid = "1234567890";
  if (form.year.value == "" || isNaN(valid) ) {
    alert( "Please enter a year." );
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>

Comment: @woopie your script runs correctly, however i think this is what you want  `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> function validate ( form ) { valid = form.year.value; if (valid == "" || isNaN(valid) ) { alert( "Please enter a year." ); return false; } return true; } </script>`  tested on  `<form onsubmit='return validate(this);'><input type='text' name='year' /><br /><input type='submit' /></form>`